# laravel paginate passing additional var

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

let say i have url like this

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb/listproduct?idcategory=3
```

but when i used laravel pagination link, my passing variabel by url disappear like this

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb/listproduct?page=2
```

i want laravel paginate to pass my url variable too like this

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb/listproduct?idcategory=3&page2
```

so far i already try to set baseurl like this

```
$listproduct = DB::table('product')->paginate(15);
$users->setBaseUrl('listproduct?idcategory=3');
```

but the result is like this **(? not &)**

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb/listproduct?idcategory=3?page2
```

i used laravel 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setPath()

```
$users->setPath('listproduct?idcategory=3');
```

or if you only want to add to the query string you may use

```
$users->appends(['idcategory' => '3'])
```

Comment: i get error like this `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' does not have a method 'setPath'`

Comment: try to change DB::table('product')->paginate(15) to Product::paginate(15)

Comment: so using elequent right? can this method use with query builder?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I'm using it with eloquent and it is working well

Comment: another alternative is to use $users->appends(['idcategory' => '3'])

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to append more arguments to your pagination link:

```
 $listproduct->appends(['idcategory' => $id])->links();
```